# starting container process caused: exec: "./entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown?

Tags: java, bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run a docker-compose but I get an error:
starting container process caused: exec: "./entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown ?

Here is the entrypoint file:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -Ddatasource.dialect="MYSQL" -Ddatasource.url="jdbc:mysql://mysql_container:3306/lavagna?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&useSSL=false" -Ddatasource.username="user" -Ddatasource.password="password" -Dspring.profile.active="dev" -jar lavagna-jetty-console.war
```

Small Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.3-jdk-8 as Builder

WORKDIR /build/

COPY entrypoint.sh .

COPY ./project/ .

RUN mvn verify

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

WORKDIR /app/

COPY --from=Builder /build/target .
COPY entrypoint.sh .

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

And the docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  lavagna:
    build: .
    container_name: lavagna_container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    container_name: mysql_container
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=lavagna
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - /home/linx/Desktop/vol:/var/lib/mysql
```

```
ERROR: for lavagna_container  Cannot start service lavagna: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "./entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown
```

Why can it not find the entrypoint.sh?

Comment: Is it in fact executable?  Does your image in fact contain GNU bash (Alpine-based images frequently won't), and if not, does changing the script's "shebang" line to `#!/bin/sh` help (you are not using any non-standard bash features)?

Comment: Does the file have executable permissions? What about running "RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh" after copying?